# Heroku / Python - script stops with error

Tags: python, heroku, yfinance

i have a python script which i want to run on the heroku plattform - everything seems fine and scheduled - but at the end i allways get an error when running on heroku (i see this in the papertrail logs)

When i run the script locally on my machine it works fine.

The error occurs when i want to read data using the yfinance module:
(obviously in the last line)

```
tday = datetime.today()
startDay = tday - timedelta(days=2200)            
print(f"Read stock price data for {stock}...")
hist_price_stock = yf.download(stock,start=startDay,end=tday)
```

This is the error message which i get from heroku / papertrail:
(on the first look it didn´t help me much)

```
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1 Read stock price data for AAPL...
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1 Exception in thread Thread-1:
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1 Traceback (most recent call last):
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     self.run()
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/multitasking/__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     return callee(*args, **kwargs)
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 167, in _download_one_threaded
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/multi.py", line 179, in _download_one
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yfinance/base.py", line 157, in history
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     data = data.json()
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
Sep 04 03:13:12 scoresupdatetickers app/worker.1 json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Sep 04 07:09:47 scoresupdatetickers heroku/scheduler.7291 Cycling
Sep 04 07:09:47 scoresupdatetickers heroku/scheduler.7291 State changed from up to complete
Sep 04 07:09:48 scoresupdatetickers heroku/scheduler.7291 Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
Sep 04 07:09:48 scoresupdatetickers heroku/scheduler.7291 Process exited with status 143
```

Any idea why this is only running locally and not when hosted on heroku?

Comment: Error with JSON - ```json.decoder.JSONDecodeError```

Comment: Any idea what the problem could be - as i have written when running this locally i have no problems at all - only when trying to run on heroku

Comment: It seems i found the problem - according to yfinance:

You're right. Based on the logs, it looks your Heroku app might be using an older version of yfinance - at least 0.1.59 or older (based on the fact that line 95 of multi.py in your logs is actually found at line 97 now)

Any idea how i can get in contact with heroku if the can upgrade the yfinance-version on their platform?

Comment: yfinance is a python package. You have to update it's version to the latest one in ```requirements.txt``` file and then Heroku will install the latest version of yfinance.

Comment: yes you are absolute right - with that it works - when you write this a the answer i will flag this as answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yfinance` is a python package.

You have to update it's version to the latest one in your `requirements.txt` file and then push those changes to Heroku.

Heroku will then install the updated version and then your app will be using the latest version of `yfinance`.